# Updating string until period is found in C

Tags: c

In this function I am going to be receiving char * words such as

```
person.vet.blah
```

and

```
word.friends.joe
```

I want to extract the first word. So for the first one I want to extract

```
 person
```

and the second one I want to extract

```
 word
```

How can I correctly do this? Here is my code:

```
char *separate_name(char *machine_name)
{
    //iterate until you find period. then return
    char absolute_name[1000];
    int i;
    for (i =0; i < strlen(machine_name); i++)
    {
        if (machine_name[i] == '.')
          absolute_name[i] = machine_name[i];

    }


    return absolute_name;
}
```

This is just segfaulting. Any ideas what I should be doing? machine_name is going to be the "person.vet.blah" and then return absolute_name which would be "person"

Comment: You return a local variable which ceases to exist after you leave the scope of the function.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "extract" instead of "abstract"?

Comment: use strtok (strtok_r, strtok_s newer functions) to tokenize your string

Comment: I do mean extract, Cornstalks. Sorry.

Comment: Turn warnings up on your compiler. Any decent compiler should warn about returning `absolute_name`.

Comment: I don't think your loop logic is correct. You want to copy into `absolute_name` if the character **is not** a dot and when it is, break out of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

### Fixing your code

As others have pointed out, you can't use `absolute_name` outside of the function in which it was defined. This is because you're when you return the variable from your function, all that is being returned is a pointer to the beginning of the array. Outside the function, the array itself no longer exists, so the pointer is invalid and you get a segfault if you try and dereference it.

You can get around this by using `malloc`. Don't forget to `free` the memory you have allocated when you are done using it.

By the way, as well as changing your loop to a `while`, I also fixed the check (you were checking `machine_name[i] == '.'`, the opposite to what you wanted).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *separate_name(char *machine_name)
{
    // allocate memory on the heap
    char *absolute_name = malloc(strlen(machine_name)+1);

    int i = 0;    
    while (i < strlen(machine_name) && machine_name[i] != '.') {
        absolute_name[i] = machine_name[i];
        ++i;
    }
    absolute_name[i] = '\0';

    return absolute_name;
}

int main() 
{
    char name1[] = "person.vet.blah";
    char *first1 = separate_name(name1);
    if (first1 != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", first1);
        free(first1);
    }

    char name2[] = "word.friends.joe";
    char *first2 = separate_name(name2);
    if (first2 != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", first2);
        free(first2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### A better alternative

`strtok` is the perfect tool for the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *separate_name(char *machine_name)
{
    return strtok(machine_name, ".");
}

int main() 
{
    char name1[] = "person.vet.blah";
    char *first1 = separate_name(name1);
    if (first1 != NULL) printf("%s\n", first1);

    char name2[] = "word.friends.joe";
    char *first2 = separate_name(name2);
    if (first2 != NULL) printf("%s\n", first2);

    return 0;
}
```

As pointed out in the comments (thanks @John), `strtok` modifies the string that is passed to it (it replaces the delimiter `.` by the `\0` null byte to mark the end of the string). This isn't a problem here but is something to be aware of.

Output using either program:

```
person
word
```

Comment: If you invert the two alternatives (strtok first) I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: +1. But you might want to store the return value to `separate_name()` into a separate variable and add a NULL-check. Calling `printf` where it is expecting a string argument and providing a NULL pointer is UB.

Comment: malloc(strlen(machine_name+1)) has an off-by-2 error.

Comment: @CAFxX I have edited to emphasise which approach I prefer but I feel that the emphasis of the answer should be on fixing the OP's code and explaining what was wrong with it.

Comment: @DaV thanks for the suggestion, I've edited to add a check for NULL.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you mean? :)

Comment: `malloc(strlen(x+1))` should be `malloc(strlen(x)+1)`

Comment: Note that the value returned by `strtok()` is just a pointer into the original string passed to it AND it modifies the original string by replacing the separator (. here) with a '\0'.  In more complex programs these can be issues you need to be aware of and handle.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *separate_name(const char *machine_name){
    static char absolute_name[1000];
    int i;
    for (i =0; i < sizeof(absolute_name)-1 ; i++){
        if(machine_name[i] == '.' || machine_name[i] == '\0'){
            absolute_name[i] = '\0';
            break;
        } else {
            absolute_name[i] = machine_name[i];
        }
    }

    return absolute_name;
}
int main(void){
    printf("%s\n", separate_name("person.vet.blah"));
    printf("%s\n", separate_name("word.friends.joe"));
    return 0;
}
```